# Adding days to a Date (retrieved from MySQL database) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to do, what I assume is, an easy task of adding days to a date.

I have a date stored in a MySQL table, in a column called `meta_date`, with the type of `DATE` (A date, supported range is 1000-01-01 to 9999-12-31)

I retrieve this date from the database as follows:

```
$thisId = 1;
$dateQuery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `sometable` WHERE `id` = '$thisId'"); 
$fetchDate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dateQuery);
$theDate = $fetchDate['meta_date'];
```

Now I add a number of days to this date.

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($theDate . " + 7 days"));
```

Next I put it back inside the database with an `UPDATE` query.

```
$editDate = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `sometable` SET `meta_date` = '$newDate' WHERE `id` = '$thisId'");
```

However the date always returns as `0000-00-00` after the update.

Am I missing something here to do with the way the date is handled in PHP?

edit: The data I first retrieve from the database (into `$theDate`) is "2016-11-30".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mysql's built in function `DATE_ADD()`

**Syntext**

`DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)` Where date is a valid date expression and expr is the number of interval you want to add.

For your case

```
UPDATE sometable
SET `meta_date` = DATE_ADD(`meta_date` , INTERVAL 7 DAY)
WHERE `id` = '$thisId';
```